# Detecting couples in photo captions with Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on a web scraping project where I am trying to extract names from a series of photo captions. I have the captions stored as a list of unicode strings such as:

`Phil Collins, with Beth and Jerry Smith`

I have been able to use`foo = re.compile(r" +with +|, +and +| +and +|, +")` and `re.split(foo)` to separate the captions into different individual names such as:

`['Phil Collins', 'Beth', 'Jerry Smith']`

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding a way to split Jane and Jerry Smith (I'm new to regular expressions) in a way that can detect their surname and produce the output:

`['Phil Collins', 'Beth Smith', 'Jerry Smith']`

I am able to detect `Beth and Jerry Smith` using `re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]+ +and +[A-Z][a-z]+ +[A-Z][a-z]+"`, but I am not sure the best way to process it once it is detected.

The problem I am trying to tackle is that I need to iterate over the list of names, detect that 'Beth' is not a full name, read 'Jerry Smith', and finally read and append 'Smith' to 'Beth' giving me a complete list of: ['Phil Collins', 'Beth Smith', 'Jerry Smith']

Is there a method in `re` that can pipe the matching substring to a function so I can modify it to include Beth's surname? Or am I even approaching this problem the right way?

Comment: Names can be *quite* complex. There's no easy, way to determine that "Beth" is really "Beth Smith" and not someone with only a single name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching the names and the delimiters with a complex RegEx, you could split the text using `re.split` and a smaller RegEx of all possible delimiters.

Here, the delimiters I see are: ", with" and "and" (with spaces at begin and end). You could create a RegEx by joining every delimiter.

```
import re

text = "Phil Collins, with Beth and Jerry Smith"

delimiters = [r",\s+with\s+", "\s+and\s+"]
regex = "|".join(delimiters)
print(re.split(regex, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
# -> ['Phil Collins', 'Beth', 'Jerry Smith']
```

**EDIT**

To join the "Beth" with "Smith" and "Jerry" with "Smith", you need to first split on the "with", and then split on the and.

```
import re

text = "Phil Collins, with Beth and Jerry Smith"

for part in re.split(",\s+with\s+", text):
    first, last = re.findall(r"(\w+(?:\s+and\s+\w+)?)\s+(\w+)",
                             part, flags=re.UNICODE)[0]
    names = re.split(r"\s+and\s+", first)
    result = [name + " " + last
              for name in names]
    print(result)
```

You get:

```
['Phil Collins']
['Beth Smith', 'Jerry Smith']
```

Comment: If you down-vote, please give an explanation in order to improve my answer.

Comment: This is effectively what I have done so far (though in a less elegant fashion). The problem I am trying to tackle is that I need to iterate over the list of names, detect that `'Beth'` is not a full name, read `'Jerry Smith'`, and finally read and append `'Smith'` to `'Beth'` giving me a complete list of: 
`['Phil Collins', 'Beth Smith', 'Jerry Smith']`

Comment: @BeninTampa: OK, I edit my code: you need to do a loop to split twice and then join the first and last names.